# How to access pixel values using NITRO NITF library using C++ bindings

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, gis, image-formats

I have a task to write a module to unpack [National Imagery Transmission Format (NITF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Imagery_Transmission_Format) images and pass around the data in memory to various processing modules. I have chosen to use the [NITRO](https://github.com/hobu/nitro) library. I am trying to figure out how to read the image and access the pixel values, but I am having trouble. I am using the C++ bindings.

I successfully compiled the library. Now, I am trying to use the unit tests to understand how to use the library, namely read an image and access the pixel values. There are also some examples [here](http://nitro-nitf.sourceforge.net/wikka.php?wakka=NitroSnippets). However, the unit tests and code snippets don't perform this task directly.

My toy example is below. I've tried variations of the code below, but I almost always get some error in `image_reader.read()`. The code below results in an error about too many bands, but if I limit the number of bands, then I don't get an error but the buffer doesn't seem to have any values in it.

I would be grateful to anyone who could give me some guidance or tips on how to use this library to access pixel values.

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

#define IMPORT_NITRO_API

#include <import/nitf.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const std::string filename = "my_image.NTF";
    nitf::Reader reader;
    nitf::IOHandle io(filename.c_str());
    nitf::Record record = reader.read(io);

    nitf::List images = record.getImages();
    nitf::ListIterator iter = images.begin(); // NITF can store more than one image - just try the first
    nitf::ImageSegment segment = *iter; 

    nitf::SubWindow window; // define a subwindow for reading - try to read the whole image although it might be slow
    unsigned int numRows = segment.getSubheader().getNumRows();
    unsigned int numCols = segment.getSubheader().getNumCols();
    const int band_count = segment.getSubheader().getBandCount();
    window.setNumRows(numRows);
    window.setNumCols(numCols);
    window.setNumBands(band_count);

    nitf::Uint32* band_list = new nitf::Uint32[band_count];
    for (nitf::Uint32 band_number = 0; band_number < band_count; band_number++)
        band_list[band_number] = band_number;

    window.setBandList(band_list);

    auto image_reader = reader.newImageReader(1); // 1 seems to be the image number: nitro-master\c\nitf\tests\test_create_xmltre.c
    std::vector< std::vector<nitf::Uint8> > buffer(band_count); // User-defined data buffers for read
    for (nitf::Uint32 band_number = 0; band_number < band_count; band_number++)
        buffer[band_number].resize(numRows * numCols);

    int padded = 0; // Returns TRUE if pad pixels may have been read
    image_reader.read(window, (nitf::Uint8**)&buffer[0], &padded);

    return 0;
}
```